# protobuf.js: print int64 Object as string in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers, proto

I'm using this great module: [protobuf.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/) for protocol buffers in node.js.

I've int64 field type (which supported by google-protocol) and I'm trying to print it to screen.

The line:

```
console.log(MessageTypeAck.decode(message));
```

Print the following:

```
{ trace: 
   [ { topic: 'Genesis', partition: 0, offset: [Object] },
     { topic: 'DataManager', partition: 0, offset: [Object] } ],
  sourceModuleName: 'DataManager',
  sourceModuleID: 10040 }
```

(offset fields are printed as `[Object]`)
And the line:

```
console.log(MessageTypeAck.decode(message).trace[1].offset.toString());
```

Prints:

```
9217
```

(The actual value).
Why does the first call doesn't call to toString() of Long object as well?

Why desired output will be:

```
{ trace: 
   [ { topic: 'Genesis', partition: 0, offset: 9217 },
     { topic: 'DataManager', partition: 0, offset: 9217 } ],
  sourceModuleName: 'DataManager',
  sourceModuleID: 10040 }
```

I've found this [issue](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/issues/50) but as I understand I shouldn't do something special to get it..

I've also found [this](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/wiki/Long) - my version (npm list protobufjs) return `protobufjs@5.0.1`

Any ideas?

Comment: I've also tried .decode64 but still doesn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Node.js `console.log` [calls `util.inspect` under the hood](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data). Which by default [has a `depth` value of 2](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options).

In order to print all properties of an object, You could call `util.inspect` directly:

```
const util = require('util');

console.log(util.inspect(
    MessageTypeAck.decode(message),
    { showHidden: true, depth: null }
));
```

Comment: Or `console.log('%j', MessageTypeAck.decode(message))` to output the object as JSON.